# How to access the href which is option in drop down list in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The x path link from IDE is: //a[contains(text(),'Alliance Entertainment Corp.(IV00000003)'

Comment: <div class="jqx-button jqx-button-bootstrap jqx-combobox-multi-item jqx-combobox-multi-item-bootstrap jqx-fill-state-normal
 jqx-fill-state-normal-bootstrap jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-bootstrap" style="overflow: hidden; float: left;">
<a data-value="IV00000003" style="float: left;" href="#">Alliance Entertainment Corp.   (IV00000003)</a>
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; float: right; min-height: 16px; min-width: 18px;">

Comment: <div style="position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 50%; margin-left: -18px; margin-top: -7px; float: none; width: 16px; height: 16px;
" class="jqx-icon-close jqx-icon-close-bootstrap"></div></div></div>

Comment: Please add any part of your question like HTML in ques rather than in comments. Use the edit link given at bottom of your question to edit a question.

Answer (score 1):

To get the href use `getAttribute()` (in java) method of WebElement. So in your case you can achieve it by:

```
String href = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Alliance Entertainment Corp.(IV00000003)'")).getAttribute("href");
```

This will return you the url to this element i.e. **http://your-site-name/#**